# How does the ActiveRecord pattern differ from the Domain Object or Data Mapper pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, datamapper

I was looking at [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/), which appeared at first glance to use the ActiveRecord ORM pattern.  Other people said that it uses the DataMapper and/or the Domain Object pattern.

What is the difference between those patterns?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The main difference between the two patterns is this:

- In the ActiveRecord you have one domain object that both knows all the business logic and how to save/update itself in the database, `user.getLinkToProfile()` and `User::find(1)`, `User::save(user)`
- In the DataMapper pattern you have one domain object that holds all the business logic, for exmaple `user.getLinkToProfile()` (or something similar) but knows *nothing* about the database in question, in addition to this you have a mapper-object that is responsible for saving, updating, selecting, etc. user objects from the database which would have `UserMapper::find(1)`, `UserMapper.save(user)`

DataMapper is potentially more complex then ActiveRecord but it's a lot easier to develop your domain model and database asynchronous than with ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 3):

Active record is very heavy, data mapper and domain object are separating those concerns out so you have a more defined set of code doing various aspects for you "domain" or "entity" objects.

I personally prefer, not that you asked, going with the separation into domain object, data mapper, probably use an assembly pattern and even a data transfer pattern to assure clear separation of what happens to data between the database an the upper tiers of an application.

...elegant and simple separations always help.